# How to open .playground file in xcode via a terminal?

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, swift-playground

I just learned the basics of the Terminal, so I was trying to open a file named `trees.playground` by following command:

```
open trees.playground
```

But terminal says:

```
No application knows how to open trees.playground.
```

How to make the terminal aware that `XCode` can open such file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Xcode should be the default opening application for `.playground` files. So following command should work:

```
open trees.playground
```

If it still does not, you can just force terminal to open it with Xcode like following:

```
open -a Xcode trees.playground
```

To make you understand the above mentioned command, I will break it down:

```
open [Open something]
-a [With application]
Xcode [Name of desired application]
trees.playground [This file]
```

In Verbose form, it would mean "Open tree.playground with an application named Xcode".

Comment: what does -a mean ?

Comment: @DeyaEldeen -a means application